# Listview to the same activity with different text on tabbed activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-tabbed-activity

I'm new at Android programming and I need your help. Please.
What I want to do.

I created listview, from listview I created OnItemClickListener to TabbedActivity.

Now I want for each listview item to show different text on TabbedActivity.

This is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
ListView listview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bolesti));

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
            }

        }
    });

    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}}
```

TabbedActivity:

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabbed, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabbed, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Tab1Opis tab1 = new Tab1Opis();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2Simptomi tab2 = new Tab2Simptomi();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3Uzroci tab3 = new Tab3Uzroci();
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                Tab4Lijecenje tab4 = new Tab4Lijecenje();
                return tab4;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Opis";
            case 1:
                return "Simptomi";
            case 2:
                return "Uzroci";
            case 3:
                return "Lijecenje";
        }
        return null;
    }
}}
```

TabbedActivity contains 4 tabs, all of them have different .java class example:

```
public class Tab2Simptomi extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simptomi, container, false);
    return rootView;
}}
```

I need to change text in every fragment when I click on different listview item.

Can you help me? Thank you.

---

Check the pictures. Thank you a lot.

[image: ListView 1]

[image: ListView 2]

Comment: You should use Intent's extras to pass data to another activity... Please do some research and read official android developer's guide before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `text` from your `MainActivity`  to `TabbedActivity` fragment `Tab2Simptomi` as below:

**1.** Pass `text` from `MainActivity` to `TabbedActivity`,  using `Intent` extras.

**Update `onItemClick()` as below:**

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("YOUR_TEXT", "Text One");
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("YOUR_TEXT", "Text Two");
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
        }

    }
});
```

**2.** Pass `text` from `TabbedActivity` to `Tab2Simptomi`, setting `bundle` as `arguments` of fragments inside `SectionsPagerAdapter`.

**In `TabbedActivity` `onCreate()` method, get `text` that was passed from `MainActivity`**

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

        // Get text
        String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_TEXT"); 

        // Pass text to SectionsPagerAdapter
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), text);

        .............
        ......................     
    }
}
```

**Update `SectionsPagerAdapter` to pass `text` to `Fragments`:**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String yourText;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String yourText) {
        super(fm);
        this.yourText = yourText;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("YOUR_TEXT", yourText);

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Tab1Opis tab1 = new Tab1Opis();
                tab1.setArguments(bundle); // Pass text to Tab1Opis fragment                   
                return tab1;

            case 1:
                Tab2Simptomi tab2 = new Tab2Simptomi();
                tab2.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab2;

            case 2:
                Tab3Uzroci tab3 = new Tab3Uzroci();
                tab3.setArguments(bundle);                    
                return tab3;

            case 3:
                Tab4Lijecenje tab4 = new Tab4Lijecenje();
                tab4.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab4;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Opis";
            case 1:
                return "Simptomi";
            case 2:
                return "Uzroci";
            case 3:
                return "Lijecenje";
        }
        return null;
    }
}}
```

**3.** Finally get `text` from individual `Frgament` and do whatever you want.

**Update `Tab2Simptomi`  as below:**

```
public class Tab2Simptomi extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simptomi, container, false);

        String finalText = getArguments().getString("YOUR_TEXT");

        // Do something with finalText
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Final Text: " + finalText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Assuming your fragment `texts` are `static`.

**1.** Pass `texts` from `MainActivity` to `TabbedActivity`,  using `Intent` extras.

**Update `onItemClick()` as below:**

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("OPIS", "Item1 :: Text for Fragment OPIS");
                intent.putExtra("SIMPTOMI", "Item1 :: Text for Fragment SIMPTOMI");
                intent.putExtra("UZROCI", "Item1 :: Text for Fragment UZROCI");
                intent.putExtra("LIJECENJE", "Item1 :: Text for Fragment LIJECENJE");
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("OPIS", "Item2 :: Text for Fragment OPIS");
                intent1.putExtra("SIMPTOMI", "Item2 :: Text for Fragment SIMPTOMI");
                intent1.putExtra("UZROCI", "Item2 :: Text for Fragment UZROCI");
                intent1.putExtra("LIJECENJE", "Item2 :: Text for Fragment LIJECENJE");
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
        }

    }
});
```

**2.** Pass `texts` from `TabbedActivity` to `Tab2Simptomi`, setting `bundle` as `arguments` of fragments inside `SectionsPagerAdapter`.

**In `TabbedActivity` `onCreate()` method, get `text` that was passed from `MainActivity`**

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> stringArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

        stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Get texts
        String textOPIS = getIntent().getStringExtra("OPIS");
        String textSIMPTOMI = getIntent().getStringExtra("SIMPTOMI"); 
        String textUZROCI = getIntent().getStringExtra("UZROCI"); 
        String textLIJECENJE = getIntent().getStringExtra("LIJECENJE"); 

        // Add text to ArrayList
        stringArray.add(textOPIS); 
        stringArray.add(textSIMPTOMI); 
        stringArray.add(textUZROCI); 
        stringArray.add(textLIJECENJE); 

        // Pass ArrayList to SectionsPagerAdapter
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), stringArray);

        .............
        ......................     
    }
}
```

**Update `SectionsPagerAdapter` to pass `text` to `Fragments`:**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> stringList;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> stringArray) {
        super(fm);
        this.stringList = stringArray;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("YOUR_TEXT", stringList.get(position)); // Get string from stringList using position

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Tab1Opis tab1 = new Tab1Opis();
                tab1.setArguments(bundle); // Pass text to Tab1Opis fragment                   
                return tab1;

            case 1:
                Tab2Simptomi tab2 = new Tab2Simptomi();
                tab2.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab2;

            case 2:
                Tab3Uzroci tab3 = new Tab3Uzroci();
                tab3.setArguments(bundle);                    
                return tab3;

            case 3:
                Tab4Lijecenje tab4 = new Tab4Lijecenje();
                tab4.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab4;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Opis";
            case 1:
                return "Simptomi";
            case 2:
                return "Uzroci";
            case 3:
                return "Lijecenje";
        }
        return null;
    }
}}
```

**3.** Finally get `text` from individual `Frgament` and do whatever you want.

**Update `Tab2Simptomi`  as below:**

```
public class Tab2Simptomi extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simptomi, container, false);

        String finalText = getArguments().getString("YOUR_TEXT");

        // Do something with finalText
        TextView yourTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
        // Show text on TextView
        yourTextView.setText(finalText);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Final Text: " + finalText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Helped, but didnt change the text. Please check the picture I posted. Regards. Thank you.

Comment: In your question you were asked about same text on 4 fragments and for this my solution will perfectly as I checked in my device. If you want show different text on different tabs based on item selection, then you need to pass string array list as same way.

Comment: from where you get those strings? from database or somewhere?

Comment: This works perfect thank you. Strings are from strings.xml.   
Can I replace text like this? ( intent1.putExtra("SIMPTOMI", R.string.opis2);)

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    intent.putExtra("Title", "Title1");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent.putExtra("Title", "Title2");
                    break;
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

In TabbedActivity,String title is Title1 or Title2 based on what was clicked in MainActivity.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("Title");
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }
}
```